# Why am I getting a python ArrtibuteError in my Google Cloud Function, preventing deployment but my code runs fine locally?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, constants

So this is the error I get when I deploy my cloud function

```
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/bin/functions-framework", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(_cli())
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1130, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1055, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1404, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/functions_framework/_cli.py", line 37, in _cli
    app = create_app(target, source, signature_type)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/functions_framework/__init__.py", line 288, in create_app
    spec.loader.exec_module(source_module)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/workspace/main.py", line 18, in <module>
    bucket = client.get_bucket(const.destination_gcs_bucket)
AttributeError: module 'constants' has no attribute 'destination_gcs_bucket'
```

Line 17 and 18 of my `main.py` is:

```
client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket(const.destination_gcs_bucket)
```

My `requirements.txt` is:

```
pandas
constants
google-cloud-storage
google-cloud-bigquery
lxml
flask
datetime
```

And my `constants.py` is:

```
destination_gcs_bucket = 'nba_teams_data'
```

I'm quite confused as this Cloud Function used to deploy just fine and I've hardly changed any code other than some business logic (regex).

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you importing the constants.py ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the OS Library and define the GCS Bucket as an environment variable on the Cloud Function

The code would be something like:

```
import os

destination_gcs_bucket = os.getenv("DESTINATION_GCS_BUCKET")
```

Where the environment variable on the cloud function is defined as:

DESTINATION_GCS_BUCKET = 'nba_teams_data'

Here is the link to the documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/env-var

Cheers,
Ben :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't put constants in requirements, but just upload a file to Google Cloud Function. And then do this:

```
from constants import *
```